# Firestore query works with flutter but not with node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried to use the same query with flutter and node.js. On flutter it works - but on node.js the API tells that a index is required. Now I've no idea how to solve my problem on node.js.

Firestore collection:

```
{
name: "NameA",
members: {
  "A7bn2": { role: "owner", "approved": true },
  "b1aw1": { role: "owner", "approved": true },
}
}
```

doesn't work :-(

```
return this.firestore.collection("projects")
  .where(`members.${this.auth.currentUser.uid}.role`,
    '==', 'owner')
```

log message:

```
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here
```

the suggested index (with the uid)

```
members.I21HsjQCL7sDgb34CgYi1.role Ascending name Ascending
```

query works with dart/flutter

```
.where('members.${_auth.currentUser!.uid.toString()}.role',
    isEqualTo: 'owner')
.snapshots()
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Is there any error or the returned data is irrelevant ?

Comment: You should see a link in the console error that points to the Firebase site where you can add the index that this requires. What does it tell you about the index required?

Comment: .. And is that all that you have in your query? Maybe you're also using .orderBy or something? Whenever you search or sort by more than one field, a composite index is required.

Comment: @funkizer thank you - the order was the difference. On node.js I've added sort by ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found in comments. Add a compound index if you need to sort or search by more than one field.

Error message has a link to where you can create the required index. Or add a `firestore.indexes.json` file and use `firebase` cli to deploy indexes from that file.